# Set encoding inside asp.net control

Tags: asp.net, encoding, user-controls

I have configured encoding inside the web config file as follows:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" fileEncoding="utf-8"
               requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

It is all working fine, except in a case where I use special characters inside .net control.

It seems that HTML from the user control does not pick up the default encoding.

Another problem is that there is no Page directive where I can declare encoding locally.

How do I resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not to adjust the webconfig file, but to save the .ascx file with proper encoding (Save with encoding UTF-8 codepage 65001 for example).

Hope I helped someone with this.